# Convert double to char array without padding in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, double, winsock

I am trying to send a double through a UDP winsock using the Sendto function but first I need to convert it to a char[]. After trying multiple approaches, the best thing I came up with is the following:

```
    // send 
    memset(buf, '\0', BUFLEN);
    double a = position.y();
    char arr[sizeof(a)];
    cout << "double" << a << endl;
    ToString(arr, sizeof(a), a);

    sendto(s, arr, strlen(arr), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen);
    cout << "Send" << arr << endl;
```

This unfortunately gives out a weird trailing padding that ruins the send operation. Any ideas on how to solve this?

My ToString function is the following:

```
void ToString(char * outStr, int length, double val)
{
     _snprintf(outStr, length, "%f", val);
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
double 0.003
Send 0.003(a bunch of gibberish)
```

Comment: my suggestion is that you simply check that sizeof double is 8 on both receiving and sending side and just send it in binary format.

Comment: Don't use character pointers or arrays of char, use std::string and possibly std::stringstream.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Binary format floats are not always portable.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that I will have to add more code to order the data since I am using a UDP socket?

Comment: wrt your problem, you are probably messing up something with buffer sizes and/or parameters to _snprintf.

Comment: btw c++11 has to_string function http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: @Galik true, but IDK if I have ever seen non IEEE754 doubles IRL, feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl And there is also endianness to consider

Comment: `double` -> `"%lf"` instead of `"%f"`?

Comment: @Galik true, that is actually problem I have seen IRL, so thank you for mentioning that.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to send the `double` as a formatted string but... why do you assume that `char arr[sizeof(double)]` will be large enough to hold the string representation of a `double`?  You might want to look at using [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

Comment: The specific cause of your problem is that `arr` isn't big enough to hold all the digits you require.

Comment: std:string and such functions won't help since they create the following error:  error C2664: 'int sendto(SOCKET,const char *,int,int,const sockaddr *,int)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that the number of bytes that the binary `double` occupies is the same length as the converted string occupies but that is unlikely.

If you have `C++11` you can do something like this:

```
void send_double(int s, sockaddr* si_other, int slen, double d)
{
    auto buf = std::to_string(d);
    sendto(s, buf.data(), buf.size(), 0, si_other, slen);
}
```

Otherwise you can do something like this:

```
void send_double(int s, sockaddr* si_other, int slen, double d)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << d;
    std::string buf = oss.str();
    sendto(s, buf.data(), buf.size(), 0, si_other, slen);
}
```

See [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)